# What does "deber de" + infinitivo mean?

Tags: modismos

Could someone please help me know what does 'deber de' + infinitivo express?

I asked one of my friends and she said that it expresses 'probabilidad', but I just wasn't sure.

Answer (score 2):

Si es lo que parece que estás preguntando, en el *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* se explica esta cuestión:

> Funciona como auxiliar en perífrasis de infinitivo que denotan obligación y suposición o probabilidad:

> a) **deber** + infinitivo. Denota obligación: «*Debo cumplir con mi misión*» (Mendoza Satanás [Col. 2002]). Con este sentido, la norma culta rechaza hoy el uso de la preposición de ante el infinitivo: «*Debería DE haber más sitios donde aparcar sin tener que pagar por ello*» (Mundo [Esp.] 3.4.94).

> b) **deber de** + infinitivo. Denota probabilidad o suposición: «*No se oye nada de ruido en la casa. Los viejos deben de haber salido*» (Mañas *Kronen* [Esp. 1994]). No obstante, con este sentido, la lengua culta admite también el uso sin preposición: «*Marianita, su hija, debe tener unos veinte años*» (VLlosa *Fiesta* [Perú 2000]).

---

Además, la Real Academia, en su serie de Dudas rápidas, abunda en la misma idea:

> Si se expresa obligación, solo es posible usar *deber* (*Debe ir cuanto antes*). Si se expresa probabilidad o suposición, lo más adecuado es usar *deber de* (*Debe de haberle ocurrido algo*), pero es aceptable también usar solo deber (*Debe haberle ocurrido algo*).

---

**Fuentes**

- https://www.rae.es/dpd/deber
- https://www.rae.es/duda-linguistica/cuando-se-usa-deber-y-cuando-deber-de

Comment: If you need my answer in english, I would try to translate it.

Comment: Perhaps include links to the relevant places for the OP to chase up themselves? Of course a translation into English would be nice although the OP does not come over to me as a first language English speaker. I suspect that all the OP needs to know is that their friend was correct.

Comment: Answer updated with the links.

Answer (score 0):

**Cuestión**; "*I asked one of my friend and she said that it expresses probabilidad, but I just wasn't sure*".

Tu amigo estaba en lo cierto solo en una parte, pues le faltaba completarla con otra parte. El "*Deber + infinitivo*" *que expresa obligación*.

Ejem. " *Debe* + infinitivo" "Tu amigo *debe* respetar las flores".

---

- El verbo **Deber** forma **dos perífrasis verbales de infinitivo** con significados diferentes en Español;
- Las perífrasis;

  - **deber** + infinitivo
  - **deber de** + infinitivo

---

- Si el Verbo "**Deber**" *expresa obligación*, solo es posible usar la forma simple, *deber* (**Debe** ir ahora). **"Debe + infinitivo**"
- Si "Deber" expresa probabilidad, suposición, creencia, lo mejor es emplear la forma más compuesta, " **deber + de**", *deber de* (**Debe de** haber ido al cine). "**Debe de + infinitivo**".

Comment: I appreciate it